# VB.net getasynckeystate log key only once

Tags: vb.net

Lets start with my code:

```
Private Sub tmrKeys_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrKeys.Tick
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 8 To 90
        If GetAsyncKeyState(i) < 0 AndAlso GlobalVariables.pressed(i) = False Then
            GlobalVariables.pressed(i) = True
            GlobalVariables.charValue = Chr(i)
        Else
            GlobalVariables.pressed(i) = False
        End If
    Next i

    If GlobalVariables.charValue <> Nothing Then
        If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown OrElse My.Computer.Keyboard.CapsLock Then
            txtLogs.Text &= GlobalVariables.charValue
        Else
            txtLogs.Text &= GlobalVariables.charValue.ToLower
        End If
        GlobalVariables.txtLength += 1
        GlobalVariables.charValue = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically it works, kind of. the key is logged to Text Box, but If I hold down a for example, I get multiple a's.

To stop this, I added the globalvariablespressed(i). Once its pressed it is set to true. It now shouldn't log that key until it is released, reseting pressed to false. But it keeps logging a, and I don't know why.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Using the `GetKeyState` function in conjunction with `GetAsyncKeyState` should give you consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should be:

```
For i = 8 To 90
    If GetAsyncKeyState(i) < 0 Then
        If GlobalVariables.pressed(i) = False  Then
            GlobalVariables.pressed(i) = True
            GlobalVariables.charValue = Chr(i)
        End If
    Else
        GlobalVariables.pressed(i) = False
    End If
Next i
...
...
```

Comment: Can you explain why a nested if question is different from using an andalso? I didn't try your code because I found a different solution.